# Why are unreferenced DLLs loading in my VB.NET app?

Tags: .net, vb.net

I have a solution containing four VB.NET projects, all targeting either .NET 4 or .NET 4 Client Profile. One is a WPF desktop application and the other three are class libraries. One of those is data access using EntityFramework connecting to MS SQL Server.

A couple of months ago, to test out a possible solution to a problem, we added a reference to `System.Data.OracleClient`. (We were doing something with reflection and needed to add a new DLL, so we picked something random.) After finishing what we were doing, we removed the OracleClient from the project and moved forward.

A bit later, I was debugging something and looking at the Output window and noticed that `System.Data.OracleClient.dll` is being loaded when a particular window is displayed. Similarly, `System.Web.dll` is loaded.

None of the projects have a reference to either OracleClient or Web. Running `dir -r -i * | Select-String "Oracle"` in PowerShell returns no results.

As far as I can tell, neither of those DLLs should be loading. Ideas?

Comment: Are there other assemblies referenced which have a dependency to those dll's?

Comment: Could there be any other dll's that one of your projects may be referencing, which may have a reference to one of these Oracle dll's?

Comment: I ran it through NDepends and [it doesn't look like anything references either](http://i.imgur.com/L9r9D.png). (The blurred names are my four projects)

Comment: Well, rename the DLL so you'll get an exception.  Now it is simple.

Comment: LOL I just tried that and if `System.Data.OracleClient.dll` is missing, neither file loads but the application runs fine. Change the name back, rerun, and they both get loaded again.

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove the reference from solution explorer -> choose a project -> references -> right click on dll and choose remove

Comment: Neither is referenced from any of the four projects.

Comment: Assuming the OP is correct, there are no references to remove. I think that was sort of the point of the question; whether there is possibly some other, indirect way in which these dll-files may be referenced.

Answer (score 0):

1. Unload all projects (right click unload)
2. Right click project files click 'edit ...vbproj'
3. Look for possible references to the dll's in the vbproj xml file.

Comment: I just checked all `.vbproj` files as well as the `.sln` and none reference either DLL anywhere.

Comment: No references in the app.config? Or a connection in Data Sources Window?

Comment: Nope. App.Config only references `System.Data.SqlClient` and `System.Data.EntityClient` (and an unrelated `Microsoft.VisualBasic.Logging.FileLogTraceListener`). The only data source is a SQL Server instance.

Comment: Tried creating a new project copying all content setting references just to make sure if its a project/solution issue?
Or adding a console app referencing the other 4 dll's in your project..

Comment: I created a new project and referenced the 3 DLLs and 1 EXE in it. That project doesn't load either unreferenced assembly.

Comment: Then it is narrowed down to the EXE project. Can you make a copy of the project and load that one up?

Comment: I finally made a new project from scratch, and it still loads those two assemblies.